# Nginx - restricting access to folders, still able to be downloaded

Tags: php, nginx

I recently made the choice to move from Apache to Nginx - as it fits our needs better.
I'm trying to block people from viewing/downloading certain files.

```
location ~ /mysql {
          deny all;
}
```

I've used this, and it works fine - our .php files now shows 403 forbidden access. But if you locate our database config.ini file, it simply downloads the file. Shouldn't this command be enough to block out that from happening?

Thanks.

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#       ...
# }
# statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied reques$
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 404 403 /404.php;
 # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location /mysql/ {
     deny all;
     }
location =  / {
     rewrite ^ /index.php;
     }
location / {
     rewrite ^(.*)$ /$1.php;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
     }
location ~ .(css|img|js)/(.+)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2;
    }
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files  $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
     }
location /doc/ {
    alias /usr/share/doc/;
    autoindex on;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#       listen 8000;
#       listen somename:8080;
#       server_name somename alias another.alias;
#       root html;
#       index index.html index.htm;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#       listen 443;
#       server_name localhost;
#
#       root html;
#       index index.html index.htm;
#
#       ssl on;
#       ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#       ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#       ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#       ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#       ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
#       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

Comment: where is located this condig.ini file

Comment: Add complete nginx config

Comment: It is most likely related to the order which nginx chooses to evaluate location matching: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location Complete config might help us to help you

Comment: I've added the complete file of my etc/nginx/sites-available/default.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
location /mysql/ {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: So now you cannot download it - but you can view the php files in that folder. Should I just add another line with my old code? Or is there a right way to go about it? Thanks.

Comment: If you also process php files in the same location block you should define a php processor or nginx will just process them as plain files. see here http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample

Comment: I think I have defined a php processor in the file. I've pasted it in the question.

Comment: php is processed in root (/) not in /mysql, so it will display them instead, make a nested php location inside mysql to deal with that.

Comment: I haven't been around - sorry for the late response. I'm kind of a newbie when it comes to Nginx, I've googled how to make a nested php location - but can't quite seem to figure it out. Should I look for something specific?

Comment: You might want to read up here first http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Passing_Uncontrolled_Requests_to_PHP